# How to get all Php functions to Java

Tags: java, php

How to get the same PHP functions in Java? Is there any .jar available for such?

- Just for an example what I mean was like this (pure Javascript doing PHP behaviors): http://phpjs.org/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As far as I know, no. But I must admit it's an interesting concept for people that do both PHP and Java, like myself (sometimes).

Comment: Do you mean in Java or in Javascript? Contrary to popular belief, the two are very different

Comment: Mark - I believe it's java, he did say "jar"...

Comment: java is not php, php is not java. There are many things between both languages, that are not comparable at all. Learn java instead of hacking around with language library ports.

Comment: Would you like generics with that?

Comment: @Mark he explecitly said "PHP function in JAVA" ;-)

Comment: I mean, Php functions converted in to Pure Java code/Java logic/To  use in Java. Just as same like: http://phpjs.org did. Where we can simply topup .jar into our Java (if requires) (like a USB stick we plug in). Can save lot of time, very useful when i tried just for test Php functions into javascript. Also, to stop reinventing  the same wheel by thinking and building, what already exist.

Comment: @Stackfan: I already understood it, but I still think, its not useful. All that stuff can be done in java, but in a java-way instead of a "looks-like-php"-way.

Comment: @Stackfan look at my answer. Quercus should be what you are asking for. it's php but with underlying Java architecture. You can define java functions and use them in php and so you can use the full power of java in php

Comment: i'd love to see a com.php.functions set that work exactly like php functions.  Not something that parses through php code, but functions that work the same way as calling identical php functions in php.  Php has very simple ways of doing things that are super annoying in java (take parsing a date string and outputting the month number for instance, 1 liner in php, 4 or 5 liner in java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you search is [quercus](http://www.caucho.com/resin-3.0/quercus/index.xtp). It's a java implementation of PHP. But i doubt that it is somehow efficient to run php code in java.

Also there are some translationframeworks that translate PHP code into Java. I once read of one but don't remember the name.

But the best way to do java is by doing java ;-)

Comment: Thank you but, i am really looking for something in Java, and i want to import Php functions in a class file or .jar so that i can use them simply like  Php p = new Php();
p.base64_encode(bla);
p.base64_decode(bla);
p.md5(bla);
p.json_encode(bla);
p.json_decode(bla);

Comment: Or better yet, several static methods on a com.php class.  So you can just call com.php.base64_encode(blah).  Surely someone somewhere has created these